# jqEasyCounter plugin - how to ignore the "(white) spaces"

Tags: jquery-plugins

Working on the textarea with jqEasyCounter plugin.

The textarea is designed as the twitter style - 140 characters, so I use the plugin for user friendly notification.

My trouble is all the spaces are counted.

Does anyone has a clue? thanks heaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces have to be counted. 
If you stop counting spaces from a textarea - you are counting the wrong amount of letters.
As result you will have problems with saving the field into a database table.